# If $x \in R$ is irreducible then $x u$ and $xy$ are irreducible where $u \in R^*$ and $y$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $x \in R$ is irreducible then $x u$ and $xy$ are irreducible where $u \in R^*$ is a unit and $y \in R$ is irreducible.

Let $R$ be a ring.

How do I see that if $x \in R$ is irreducible then:

- $x u$ is irreducible, where $u \in R^*$ is a unit
- $xy$ is irreducible, where $y \in R$ is irreducible

I've been trying to reach a contradiction, but I'd no luck in doing so.

Comment: Well the second part is clearly not true, since $xy$ is a product of two non-units: $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Since $u$ is a unit, there exists a $v\in R$ such that $uv=1$. Now suppose $xu = \alpha \beta$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in R$. Then right multiply by $v$ to get $x=xuv = \alpha \beta v$. Now apply the definition of irreducibility to $\alpha \beta v$ to obtain either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ must be a unit. For example assume $\alpha$ is *not* a unit, and show $\beta v$ must be a unit, hence $\beta$ is a unit.

Comment: @Prometheus please do not answer in the comments: answer in the solution section!

Comment: Thank you very much @Prometheus.

Answer (score 1):

Showing $xu$ is irreducible is a straightforward application of the definition. Proof by contradiction is possible, but usually you pass it by in favor of a direct proof.

Suppose $xu=ab$. Then $x=abu^{-1}$. Since $x$ is irreducible, $a$ is a unit or else $bu^{-1}$ is a unit. If $bu^{-1}=v$ is a unit, then since the product of units is a unit,  $b=vu$ is a unit. Thus either $a$ or $b$ is a unit, and we've verified $xu$ is irreducible.

As noted in the comments, the second point is clearly false. If $x,y$ are two irreducibles, then $xy$ is clearly a product of two things which aren't units. You could say that $xy$ is always *reducible* in such a case. Maybe that was the intent.